# Pass ArrayList to servlet?

Tags: java, json, servlets, arraylist

How will I pass the data as an ArrayList into my servlet?

```
<Table id="table1">
     <tr>
          <td>
              <input type="hidden" value="test1_1" name="name1_1" />
          </td>
         <td>_
              <input type="hidden" value="test2_1" name="name2_" />
          </td>
         <td>
              <input type="hidden" value="test3_1" name="name3_1" />
          </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td>
              <input type="hidden" value="test1_2" name="name1_2" />
          </td>
         <td>
              <input type="hidden" value="test2_2" name="name2_2" />
          </td>
         <td>
              <input type="hidden" value="test3_2" name="name3_2" />
          </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td>
              <input type="hidden" value="test1_3" name="name1_3" />
          </td>
         <td>
              <input type="hidden" value="test2_3" name="name2_3" />
          </td>
         <td>
              <input type="hidden" value="test3_3" name="name3_3" />
          </td>
     </tr>
</Table>




List<Model> newList = new ArrayList<Model>();
```

The servlet newList must contains 3 Model

```
Model1 with value of [getSomething1 = test1_1, getSomething2 = test2_1, getSomething3 = test3_1]
Model2 with value of [getSomething1 = test1_2, getSomething2 = test2_2, getSomething3 = test3_2]
Model3 with value of [getSomething1 = test1_3, getSomething3 = test2_3, getSomething3 = test3_3]
```

And this will not limit to 3 Model in a list but will depends on the number of row.

It will create a number of models based on the number of row in the JSP.

Comment: If the hidden input fields are submitted as part of a form to the correct URL, you should get them as part of the HttpServletRequest parameters

Comment: you can pass the data in json fromat to servlet and use gson to get Java object from json string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass it as an ArrayList, but you can read it as a String[] if you give all the inputs you want in the array the same name.

```
 <input name='test' />
 <input name='test' />
 <input name='test' />
```

In your servlet, use `request.getParameterValues(name)` (which returns a String[]) rather than `request.getParameter(name)` which only returns one value.

```
 String[] testValues = request.getParameterValues("test");
```

Comment: Just to add on what david has said, you can also use `request.getParamterMap();` which will return `Map<String, String[]>` where the key is the name of the parameters and the string array are your values.